# Ajax Toolkit Calendar is not working

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I try to use ajax calander extender but it is not working. Actually this code is working another solution but in this solution it does nothing.
Here is the my html code

```
   <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>

 <asp:TextBox ID="txtTalepTarihi" runat="server" placeholder="" class="mid"></asp:TextBox>
                        <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="calVerilisTarihi" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtTalepTarihi" Format="dd/MM/yyyy">
                        </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnGetir" runat="server" Text="Getir" CssClass="orange myOrangeButton_withLeftMargin" OnClick="btnGetir_OnClick" Style="padding-top: 0px !important" />
```

here is my web.config

```
 <configSections>
 <sectionGroup name="system.web">
      <section name="sanitizer" requirePermission="false" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.ProviderSanitizerSection, AjaxControlToolkit" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

system.web>
    <sanitizer defaultProvider="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider" type="AjaxControlToolkit.Sanitizer.HtmlAgilityPackSanitizerProvider"></add>
      </providers>
    </sanitizer>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: Did you try to update to the latest [v15.1](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases) and check if it works?

Comment: thanks for advice it works when i update v15.1 and change toolkitscriptmanager to script manager @Mikhail Tymchuk

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1.Add ajax Toolkit from Nuet Packages

2.use the below Code:

```
<asp:scriptmanager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server" ></asp:scriptmanager>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStudentDOB" runat="server" type="text">
<span id="calendarIcon"><i class="fa fa-calendar">
<ajaxtoolkit:calendarextender id="CalendarExtender1" runat="server"targetcontrolid="txtStudentDOB" popupbuttonid="calendarIcon"  Format="MM/dd/yyyy">
</ajaxtoolkit:calendarextender>
```

3.A ScriptManager is used to avoid the following error:"A ScriptManager is required on the page to use ASP.NET AJAX Script."